# Error using path_provider package in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to get the application documents directory using the path_provider package in flutter. I am using the hive database and so I need the path.

Here's my code:

```
void main() async {
  final appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); //error is on this line
  Hive.init(appDocsDir.path);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
E/flutter (18811): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (18811): #0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:142:86)
E/flutter (18811): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:148:36)
E/flutter (18811): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:331:12)
E/flutter (18811): #3      MethodChannelPathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsPath (package:path_provider_platform_interface/src/method_channel_path_provider.dart:50:10)
E/flutter (18811): #4      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:138:40)
E/flutter (18811): #5      main (package:my_app/main.dart:9:28)
E/flutter (18811): #6      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:25)
E/flutter (18811): #7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter (18811): #8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (18811): #9      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1789:10)
E/flutter (18811): #10     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1777:12)
E/flutter (18811): #11     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:138:5)
E/flutter (18811): #12     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
E/flutter (18811): #13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter (18811):
```

I am running the app on an android device connected through usb (Using flutter run). I am using the latest version of flutter and the packages.

How can I fix this?

Thank You!

Comment: can you try implementing this logic after running runApp ? maybe in the initState of the MyApp Widget

Comment: No able to add it in initSate as it says that initState should not be asynchronous. (Async is used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem using `Hive.initFlutter()`. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';


void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter()
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: what does the user see in the UI while awaiting for Hive.initFlutter to finish?

Comment: The app runs. Hive..initFlutter() doesn't take a long time.

Comment: yeah, but what if I await a task that could take about 5 seconds?

Comment: where is the data then written to. Will this be a directory specific to the app, to hive or just some directory. In the latter case, does it always find the directory again, when loading? It is really strange that the path_provider throws this error - I am also struggling with this

Comment: I am unable to find anything online about where Hive stores the data, but I believe it stores it in the application directory only and yes, it's able to find the directory again as it knows where it had stored the previous data.

Comment: @Adnan You can use FutureBuilder

Answer (score 4):

Edit: as of the comments I've received, this answer seems to not be the best method. please refer to [@Pythony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67699635/12555423)

try making these calls in the initState of the MyApp Widget.

like this:

```
initDocs() async {
  final appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocsDir.path);
}

@override
void initState() {
  initDocs();
  super.initState();
}
```

or:

```
@override
void initState() {
  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((e)=>Hive.init(e.path));
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But there is an error. It says that hive needs to be initialized and also this - ```Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)```  I think that hive checks for initialization in the main method only.

Comment: When I used the second method the error occurred. But when I use the first method, the error occurs for a split second and then the app continues normally.

Comment: This happens when I open a box.

Comment: well then, I've never used hive, but it may take seconds to initialize, so your home screen is trying to build before it is initialized. as a solution, I suggest wrapping your home screen with a FutureBuilder, and await hive initialization properly.
here is an example app: https://dartpad.dev/8261b41c81136230706c0cb666aceb42

Comment: Yeah, I have used FutureBuilder only and if the snapshot has error then it shows an error screen. So the error screen is visible for a second and then the correct screen.
According to the logs the problem is in path_provider. Why doesn't it work in main()?

Comment: can you try this:

initDocs() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocsDir.path);
}
@override
void initState() {
  initDocs();
  super.initState();
}

Comment: Still getting the error, but no problem! The screen on which I am using Hive will open later into the app and till then the problem will have happened. Is there any danger to the execution of the app if this error is ignored?

Comment: well you should always try to not ignore such problems, but if it works for now, you can ignore it and take a look back with a clearer head before releasing your app.

Comment: Well, why doesn't it work in the main function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232883/discussion-between-adnan-and-pythony).

Comment: This creates problems too if you have other screens that reference the box before their build method

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple solution, you should write the code below before: *await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();*

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

It should look like this

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 final appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

It should help (it helped to me at least)

Comment: This solution does not works for isolate as UI is available only on root isolate